# How can I heal Talion?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

It seems that plants have been omitted in Shadow of War, so that isn't a viable way to heal Talion.

When I am low on health, what options do I have for healing Talion?

The game has been a little light on instruction, except for a tooltip mentioning something about being able to heal by draining rats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a [nerdburglars question](https://nerdburglars.net/gamefaq/post/how-do-you-restore-your-health-in-shadow-of-war):

> At the start of the game, you will be instructed to press circle or B to interrogate an enemy. If you do the same to a regular enemy that is not a worm, you will be able to draw the life force out of them and heal you. If you spot any rats you can do the same to them for a quick kill and some easy health. You can do this while in combat, but it is obviously difficult to do if other enemies are attacking you. The drain seems to go a bit slower when enemies are aware of your presence, so it pays to use stealth.

Comment: Is this just brand, or does dominate heal you as well?

Comment: @DavidYell I have no idea. I think you can't dominate rats.

Comment: Dominating will heal you up just fine. If you want a reliable method of doing this in combat, one of the upgrades lets you brand/dominate in combat using your might bar. Alternately, you can duck around a corner and try to nab a stealth brand, usually pretty successful if you drop line of sight and drop in from above.

Comment: Turns out this is covered in the game guide! https://i.imgur.com/G96hUW4.jpg

Comment: I had completely discarded the tips about draining rats, as I had interpreted the tip to focus on **worms** (who **rat** on the captains). Good to know they mean **actual** rats!

Comment: Don't discount the value of Brutalize with a Life Gem on your dagger.  The healing can be beefy!